# 8-places decimal number splitting and reconstruncting

Tags: python, math, random, decimal

I am trying to figure a method to split a number in to pieces, and when i later add them get the same result. For example, the following pseudo-code is needed.

1. Take a number with 8 decimal places: 2.22222222
2. Subtract a random 8 decimal place number from #1, and store it in to a list
3. Repeat #2 until #1 is 0.00000000
4. Add each list item with each other and get 2.22222222

I tried several implementations but they're all useless that's why i don't provide any so-far code...
Thank you.

Comment: I assume you want to work with floats/doubles? Are you aware of the precision issues with decimal values? And how would you deal with the situation when the first number gets negative (less than 0, where the process would stop)?

Comment: the road to hell is paved with float comparisons. if you have a fixed number of decimal places, you should definitely go for integers.

Comment: if you say "random", what distribution do you mean exactly? your pseudo-code can produce as many splits as you want if the step size is small enough.

Comment: @Sam there is not a chance that i could have 0 or less, i am planning to give the 8-places numbers by hand!! :) Pavel Yes, i'm going to have fixed number of decimals... but i need to split them randomly in to list :/

Comment: What if the first number ends up being 0.0123? Then you could only subtract a 4-decimal-places number (0.0123) from it to get to 0. Why do the subtracted numbers need to have 8 decimal places?

Comment: @Pavel by "random" i mean (pseudo): random(from_0.00000001, to_current_max)... until the input reaches zero

Comment: so you're cool with having up to `2.22222222/0.00000001 = 222222222` elements in your split list?

Comment: Yes sure! But i need a subtraction methodology not a division, just because i need to have the same result by adding the last listed results with each other....

Comment: Have you considered using the `decimal` module? `decimal.Decimal` will hold these things while avoiding some of the floating point pitfalls.

Comment: Oh, and i need it to have some kind of randomness in subtraction... (first loop subtracts eg. 0.01000000, second loop subtracts eg. 0.10000000 etc)

Comment: why not split the number in a known number of non-random chunks (a complicated way to say "division") and then add some random noise?

Comment: @Pavel because i need the total number splitted in to different portions :/

Comment: that's what random noise is for

Answer (score 0):

@user3745919, your requirements (2) and (3) are not well-defined. Subtracting a series of random numbers from another number will not necessarily ever hit zero exactly.

That said, here's a fairly literal-minded interpretation using the [Python 2.7 `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). Note that the sum of the generated list **will not** add up to the original `d` due to the issue I just mention:

```
from decimal import *
from random import random
getcontext().prec = 8

d = Decimal('2.22222222')
print "Original value d:", d

l = []
while d > Decimal('0'):
    r = Decimal(random()).quantize(Decimal('1.00000000'))
    print "Random number in [0,1) rounded to 8 digits:", r
    l.append(r)
    d -= r

print "Sum of all random numbers:", sum(l)
print "Original d - sum:", d
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What if there was a way of getting the random number like so (pseudo): random(FROM_0.00000001, TO_VALUE_OF_D_NOW)?

Comment: You could easily modify the above code to do just that. This sounds like a homework assignment to begin with, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to complete.

Comment: Thank you very very much, i will try to do it, but i know i will mostly fail (the only way of getting a random number between range, doesn't involve decimal places but i will try harder!)... oh by the way it's not a home work! :) Thank you again!

Comment: The reason that this seems like a homework assignment is that you haven't given any explanation for what this code is actually supposed to do. Even this last piece ("generate a random number in the range [0,x]”) is subject to several interpretations depending on the distribution requirements for the result. For example, there's no way for the last number in the list to be uniformly distributed over the same interval as the others given your constraint that they sum exactly to the original value. This may be very bad news for some applications.

Comment: @user3745919 if you are satisfied with this answer then please mark it as the answer. It will be helpful for others trying to find similar answers and also giving points to Dan.